# How to hide keyboard automatically in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I want to hide the keyboard automatically when switching one `fragment` to another `fragment(navigation)`  **without** creating additional functions.

Answer (score 0):

this function should do your job....you can call this function at the start of your activity

```
fun View.hideKeyboard() {
    val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method while switching from one fragment to another

```
fun Context.hideKeyboard(view: View) {
    val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}
```

use it like below

```
activity.hideKeyboard(view)
```

Comment: Updated answer, Please check